# Unexpected result from call to Newtonsoft.Json from F#

Tags: f#, json.net

I am not getting the expected result from this F# code. I would expect t to contain values as a result of the call to JsonSchema.Parse(json) but instead it is empty. What am I doing wrong?

```
open Newtonsoft.Json
open Newtonsoft.Json.Schema

let json = """{
  "Name": "Bad Boys",
  "ReleaseDate": "1995-4-7T00:00:00",
  "Genres": [
    "Action",
    "Comedy"
  ]
}"""

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let t  = JsonSchema.Parse(json)  
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Comment: A valid JSON string requires double quotes. Remember that JSON !== JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you ChaosPandon, I fixed that and edited the question but I am still getting an empty result.

Comment: I think the problem is that Jsonschemer.Parse loads a schema, which isn't what you want - see here http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/JsonSchema.htm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As John Palmer points out, `JsonSchema.Parse` parses a JSON *schema*, but from your question, it looks as though you want to parse a normal JSON *value*. This is possible with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`:

```
let t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject json
```

However, the signature of `DeserializeObject` is to return `obj`, so that doesn't particularly help you access the values. In order to do so, you must cast the return value to `JObject`:

```
let t = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject json) :?> Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject
let name = t.Value<string> "Name"
```

Json.NET is designed to take advantage of C#'s `dynamic` keyword, but the exact equivalent of that isn't built into F#. However, you can get a similar syntax via [FSharp.Dynamic](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/FSharp.Dynamic#fsharpdynamic--):

```
open EkonBenefits.FSharp.Dynamic

let t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject json
let name = t?Name
```

Notice the `?` before `Name`. Keep in mind that JSON is case-sensitive.

Now, `name` still *isn't a string*, but rather a `JValue` object, but you can get the string value by calling `ToString()` on it, but you can also use `JValue`'s `Value` property, which can be handy if the value is a number instead of a string:

```
let jsonWithNumber = """{ "number" : 42 }"""
let t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject jsonWithNumber
let actual = t?number?Value
Assert.Equal(42L, actual)
```

Answer (score 4):

I recommend to use Json type provider instead.