# No parameterless constructor defined for this object error when using HttpPost in F# mvc 5

Tags: f#, asp.net-mvc-5

Using the [F# MVC 5 Visual Studio extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/39ae8dec-d11a-4ac9-974e-be0fdadec71b) and it works perfect for GET requests. However, I'm getting a `No parameterless constructor defined for this object` error when trying to perform a `POST`.

Here's the method in the `HomeController`:

```
[<HttpPost>] 
member this.Edit product =
    Products.updateProduct product

    this.RedirectToAction("Index")
```

Here's the `Product` type it's using where I guess the problem is originating:

```
type Product = {
  ProductId: int
  ProductName: string
  ProductCount: int
  ProductPrice: string
}
```

Is it possible to fix this within the type or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: Adding the `[<CLIMutable>]` attribute to `Product` might do the trick.

Comment: @Daniel That worked! Feel free to put it as an answer and I'll accept. If you can, perhaps you can give a quick reason to why that's needed? Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22789985/126014 Explanation: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/10/15/easy-aspnet-web-api-dtos-with-f-climutable-records

Comment: See also http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/03/19/posting-json-to-an-f-web-api

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, @MarkSeeman! Curious, though, since it compiles to an internal mutable type, do you still have the immutability of the F# type in your code?

Comment: Yes, to F# it still looks immutable. That's the whole point :)

Comment: Thanks again, @MarkSeemann! Makes much more sense now. :]