# Controller's Post method always has null property values on parameter (ASP.Net Core WebAPI & F#: )

Tags: f#, asp.net-core-webapi

My Controller's *Post* method always has null property values on parameter when triggered.

**Environment:**

> I'm using *ASP.Net Core WebAPI* with *F#*.

**Attempt:**

I tried to apply a suggestion from this [link](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/03/19/posting-json-to-an-f-web-api/) to my Startup.fs file:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver <-
        Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
```

However, *GlobalConfiguration* is an unrecognized type.

Here's a larger view of my attempt:

```
type Startup private () =
    new (configuration: IConfiguration) as this =
        Startup() then
        this.Configuration <- configuration

        // *** I INSERTED THIS BELOW *** //
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver <-
            Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
```

**Similar questions:**

I did review this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741943/web-api-post-body-object-always-null). However, nothing worked.

**HTTP Post:**

This is the *Post* method where I keep observing null property values on my parameter:

```
[<HttpPost>]
member x.Post(request:DataTransfer.Request) = (* "request" parameter is always null *)

    request |> Query.carriers  
            |> function
               | Error _     -> x.StatusCode(500) :> IActionResult
               | Ok carriers -> x.Ok(carriers)    :> IActionResult
```

The actual type is defined here:

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type Request = { 
    RequestId : string 
    Customer  : Customer
    ItemQtys  : ItemQty seq
}
```

**Client:**

My client app makes the following call:

```
let client   = WebGateway.httpClient APIBaseAddress
let response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("carriers", request) |> toResult
```

Here's the request type on the client:

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type Request = { 
    RequestId : string 
    Customer  : Customer
    ItemQtys  : ItemQty seq
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I then attempted to apply a suggestion from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789504/f-json-net-6-0-and-webapi-serialization-of-record-types/26036775#26036775) and also using this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35772387/jsonserializersettings-and-asp-net-core). It didn't work though.

```
member this.ConfigureServices(services: IServiceCollection) =
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
            .AddJsonOptions(fun opt -> 

                               let resolver = Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver()
                               resolver.NamingStrategy <- null
                               opt.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver <- resolver

                           ) |> ignore
```

**Postman:**

[image]
[image]

**Screenshots:**

[image]

**Partial Success:**

The following seems promising:

[image]

Hence, the code above results in actual values sent from the client. However, I haven't found a way to convert the object into the data transfer type that I need.

Comment: Try using the DefaultContractResolver? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789504/f-json-net-6-0-and-webapi-serialization-of-record-types/26036775#26036775

Comment: And what are you sending? Post the JSON and the request details in general, along with what you're using to make that request `HttpClient`/Postman/etc. If you're making the request in code, post that code.

Comment: Might also be useful to see the HTTP request you're sending.

Comment: @IsaacAbraham - I'm not able to find the namespace for resolving Formatters.JsonFormatter. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ScottNimrod While I am not verse in f# does this allow for parameter attributes? Could be that you are just missing [FromBody] on the action parameter.

Comment: @ScottNimrod This also looks like a mixing of versions. `GlobalConfiguration` is not part of asp.net-core. That was from previous version.

Comment: @Nkosi - I've tried that attribute as well. However, some documentation led me to believe that FromBody is for KeyValue pairs and not for a fairly complex structure.

Comment: @ScottNimrod again that is from previous version. in core it is to explicitly tell model binder where to bind data.

Comment: `member x.Post([<FromBody>]request:DataTransfer.Request)`

Comment: I've tried that without any success. I believe it has to do with me using F#'s record type that isn't getting resolved appropriately.

Comment: @ScottNimrod Perhaps that no longer exists in ASP .NET Core - it is (or was!) part of Newtonsoft.Json.

Comment: @IsaacAbraham I added an update

Comment: Is your request actually send in camal case?

Comment: An "easy" way to check if it is the record type is to try with a class?

Comment: Is your record defined _inside_ a module? This has been known to throw off lots of different reflection-based libraries across the ecosystem (i.e. moving the record might help).

Comment: @pblasucci I tried moving the record type outside of a module but I'm observing the same issue.

Comment: The following retrieves the value: member x.Post([<FromBody>] request:Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject) = ...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to mess with Contract Resolvers in ASP.NET Core to use camel-case and F# record types, as you did with ASP.NET.  I would take all of that out, or try creating a simple test project to get it working, then go back and make the appropriate changes to your real project.  With no additional configuration, you should be able to get something working just by following these steps:

1. Run `dotnet new webapi -lang F#`
2. Add the following type to `ValuesController.fs`:

```
    [<CLIMutable>]
    type Request =
    {
        Name: string
        Value: string        
    }
```

3. Change the `Post` method to be something like this:

```
    [<HttpPost>]
    member this.Post([<FromBody>] request:Request) =
        this.Created(sprintf "/%s" request.Name, request)
```

4. Debug the service to validate that it works by sending the following request in PostMan:

```
    {
        "name": "test",
        "value": "abc"
    }
```

You should see the request object echoed back with a 201 response.

Comment: Thanks but I'm still observing null property values on my record parameter even when I reference the example you provided.

Comment: @ScottNimrod Can you update your question with a snap from PostMan or Fiddler of the request body you're sending?

Comment: I'm not an expert with Postman. However, I provided some screenshots.

Comment: @ScottNimrod Ah, ok, I see the problem (at least with the example).  You need to use the "raw" option under body type, then use application/json as the content type, and paste in the JSON above.  In your real service, are you trying to process JSON data, or a form?  If JSON, are you sending the application/json content-type header?

Comment: I attempted to apply your feedback. However, I'm still not able to get Postman to work with HTTP Post. I did update the screenshots though.

Comment: @ScottNimrod Any chance you could upload your sample project?

Comment: I worked around the issue by sending a post request on the client using a string value instead of the CLIMutable record type. Then on the server, I deserialized the string value on the post method into the record type I needed.